# C# linq to sql have no translation for string.join in order by

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a problem where I am `string.join` on a subselect which works but when I order by that column I get the error that it does not have a translation

It works is I use `ToList` before `OrderBy` but I need to still have it as a queryable

```
var result = v.Select(x => new v_class() {
  IDX = x.idx,
  ID = x.id,
  unit = string.Join(",", (from g in crm.g 
   join gv in crm.gv on g.idx equals gv.gFkey
   where (gv.vfkey ?? 0) == x.idx
   select g.desc
  ).ToArray()),
}).ToList();
```

I would like to know if I can orderby unit without using to list

Comment: Please show the code with the ordering that courses the error and the exception that you get

Comment: instead of ToList i used AsQueryAble()
`result =  result.OrderByDescending(a => a.g.Length).ToList();`

Comment: Well `a` won't have a properly of `g` according to your code above.. Please submit the code that causes the error

Comment: `result = result.OrderByDescending(a => a.unit.Length).ToList();`
not allowed so submit real code sorry

Comment: Modify your original question to show a simple example that has the same error. Currently you have no `OrderBy` in your code.

Comment: `var result = v.Select(x => new v_class() {
  IDX = x.idx,
  ID = x.id,
  unit = string.Join(",", (from g in crm.g 
   join gv in crm.gv on g.idx equals gv.gFkey
   where (gv.vfkey ?? 0) == x.idx
   select g.desc
  ).ToArray()),
}).OrderByDescending(a => a.unit).ToList();`

Comment: it say i cant use string join since its not support but it works without the orderby